# How can I add a CRF layer (tfa.text.crf_log_likelihood) from tensorflow addons on a bi-lstm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, crf

I am working on a SRL for Amharic Language, and I'm wondering - how can I add the CRF from tensorflow-addon's crf_log_likelihood with the transition params and decode it?

tensorflow-version is 2.x

The Input(x) is of shape (5602, 32, 5) # a sentence list of 5602 lines, each with 32 words embedded with size=5 of FastText
And The Tag(y) # a tag list with n_tags = 23 in "IOB" with "sparse" of shape (5602, 32) and "categorical"(one-hot encoding) of shape (5602, 32, 23)
Here's the code:

```
model = Sequential()

forward_layer = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)
backward_layer = LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True,go_backwards=True)

model.add(Bidirectional(forward_layer, backward_layer=backward_layer, input_shape=(x.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(23, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.summary()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please try to keep your titles concise, without conversational elements or info already provided in the tags (edited).